# Bag-of-Words (BoW) with k-means clustering

Tags: matlab, machine-learning, cluster-analysis, cluster-computing, k-means

I created this matlab code that perform a BoW model and then add k-means clustering.

```
% Load text data and preprocess it
filename = "sonnetsPreprocessed.txt";
str = extractFileText(filename);
textData = split(str,newline);
documents = tokenizedDocument(textData);
cleanedDocuments = addPartOfSpeechDetails(documents);
cleanedDocuments = normalizeWords(cleanedDocuments,'Style','lemma');
cleanedDocuments = erasePunctuation(cleanedDocuments);
cleanedDocuments = removeShortWords(cleanedDocuments,2);
cleanedDocuments = removeLongWords(cleanedDocuments,15);

% Show the number of documents
numDocuments = numel(textData);
disp(['Number of documents: ', num2str(numDocuments)]);

% Create a bag-of-words model
cleanedBag = bagOfWords(cleanedDocuments);
cleanedBag = removeInfrequentWords(cleanedBag,2);

% Store vocabulary and display vocabulary size
vocabulary = cleanedBag.Vocabulary;
vocabSize = numel(vocabulary);
fprintf('Vocabulary size: %d\n', vocabSize);

% Cluster the bag-of-words features using k-means
% numFeatures = 100;
% [featureVector, ~] = kmeans(full(cleanedBag.Counts),numFeatures,'MaxIter',1000);

% Cluster the bag-of-words features using k-means
numFeatures = 100;
counts = full(cleanedBag.Counts);
centroids = counts(randperm(size(counts,1),numFeatures),:);
idx = zeros(size(counts,1),1);
for i = 1:1000
    % Assign each point to the closest centroid
    for j = 1:size(counts,1)
        distances = sum((repmat(counts(j,:),numFeatures,1) - centroids).^2, 2);
        [~, closestCentroid] = min(distances);
        idx(j) = closestCentroid;
    end
    
    % Update centroids
    for k = 1:numFeatures
        centroids(k,:) = mean(counts(idx==k,:),1); %each row in cleanedBag.Counts is assigned to a cluster, resulting in a single integer label for each document in the corpus.
    end
    
    % Check for convergence
    if i > 1 && isequal(idx, prevIdx)
        break;
    end
    prevIdx = idx;
end
featureVector = idx;

% Visualize the clustered features using a word cloud
figure
wordcloud(cleanedBag.Vocabulary(featureVector));

% Show histogram of feature vector
histogram(featureVector);


% Display vocabulary size after clustering
vocabulary = cleanedBag.Vocabulary(featureVector);
disp("Vocabulary size after clustering: " + numel(vocabulary));
```

Why the featureVector is 154, the same lenght of the documents in corpus? Is this correlation logically plausible? Do i perform clustering in the right way? My goal is to reduce the vocabulary to 100 words through k means clustering, how can i do that? k = 100 words

Comment: Can you try it to see if it is correct?

Comment: i edited the post. The script has no error, my question was if it was logically plausible. My goal is to reduce the vocabulary to 100 words through k means clustering, how can i do that? k = 100 words